# gpg2 --symmetric and passphrase

Tags: gnupg

Trying to encrypt files using gpg (GnuPG) from command line, using AES256. 
 To encrypt:

```
gpg2 --cipher-algo AES256 --symmetric file
```

To decrypt:

```
gpg2 --output file --decrypt file
```

Question is, when encrypting, it asks for a passphrase, but when decrypting, it DOESN'T ask for a passphrase. Is it normal? Why I can decrypt without entering a passphrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gpg2` always includes the encryption master key to comply with the latest DHS consumer encryption standard.

No, kidding, actually `gpg2` always starts an "agent" that holds on to your passphrases for you. Do:

```
killall -w gpg-agent
```

And then try to decrypt again - it should ask for the password again.